# React Native stuck when trying to run the project

Tags: react-native

[image: Unexpected error while trying to run the project]

I got stuck when trying to run react native project using `npx expo start` and even I tried to find out some possible solutions thoroughly it still does not work. Can anyone help figure out where is the problem?